# Laravel vuejs Uncaught (in promise) Response when post an item

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I use vue.js and Laravel 5.4.

I try to save an item in the database. For that I have:

vue.js file:

```
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="product.name">
<button @click="create">Create</button>
```

script:

```
data(){
    return{
            product: {
                name: ''
            }
        }
    },

    methods: {
        create() {
            this.$http.post('api/products', this.product)
            .then(response => {
                this.$router.push('/feed');
            })
        }
    }
 }
```

In the main.js file I defined:

```
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://localhost/';
```

In the api.php of the laravel project I have:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function (){
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
 });
```

ProductsController:

```
public function index()
{
    return Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::create($request->all());
    return $product;
}
```

My route list:

```
 | GET|HEAD  | api/products | products.index 
 | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@index                              
 | api,auth:api |


 | POST | api/products| products.store
 | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@store
 | api,auth:api |
```

When i click the create button I get the following error:

POST http://localhost/api/products 500 (Internal Server Error)

Uncaught (in promise) Response {url: "http://localhost/api/products", ok: false, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers: Headers…}

When instead in the create method I write: this.$http.get('api/products')
then everything seems working.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think it can be the CSRF protection, try disabling it or sending the CSRF code with your api calls

Comment: @YohananBaruchel CSRF protection would throw a TokenMismatchException (which is not realted to a 500 error IIRC). Anyway, that's a point the OP should think about too.

Comment: Further I use laravel cors package

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: So try looking at your error_log file

Comment: error 500 means you have a problem in your php script :)